# Sorting array by even and odd numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using javascript `sort()` method, I am trying to do sorting a list but sorting have in a group of even numbers and odd numbers.

The code which I tried is working fine with small list but if the list becomes big its not getting me proper result. Here is my code.

```
var n = [10,20,21,4,5,6,7,99,0,12,13];
//var n = [10,20,0,12];
n.sort(function(a,b){
 if (a % 2 !=b % 2 ){
   return a%2;
  }else {
    return a - b; 
  }
});
```

The above code gives me as per accepted result like this 
Ans - `[0, 4, 6, 10, 12, 20, 5, 7, 13, 21, 99]` and the second Ans is:- `[0, 10, 12, 20]`

Working fine with this lists but if I changed into this

```
var n = [10,20,21,4,5,6,7,99,0,12,13,10,20,21,4,5,6,7,99,0,12,13,10,20,21,4,5,6,7,99,0,12,13,10,20,21,4,5,6,7,99,0,12,13];
```

But in this case the result is something like this which is not proper.

Giving me Ans like this

`[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 5, 12, 5, 12, 5, 20, 20, 20, 20, 5, 12, 7, 7, 7, 7, 13, 13, 13, 13, 21, 21, 21, 21, 99, 99, 99, 99]` its a mixing of odd and even numbers.

Its giving me not proper result. Any suggestion.

Comment: Please define, "Not a proper result"

Comment: Please add the desired output to the question body.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short of the shortest:

```
n.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a % 2 - b % 2 || a - b;
});
```

To make it work with negative numbers we can add [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs):

```
n.sort(function(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a % 2) - Math.abs(b % 2) || a - b;
});
```

Or even more compact variant using [*bitwise AND*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.26_%28Bitwise_AND%29):

```
n.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a & 1) - (b & 1) || a - b;
});
```

The most compact version (ES6):

```
n.sort((a, b) => (a & 1) - (b & 1) || a - b);
```

Comment: that short version is beautiful :)

Comment: Good job! I started writing an answer, but gave up as soon as I saw this. Elegant and correct.

Comment: @VisioN: It does not work with negative numbers correctly (see my answer).  Also, if a and b are equal, the results are undefined by the ECMAScript spec per MDN:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @aeoril Problem with negative numbers can be easily fixed. Regarding equality, see MDN: *If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns `0`, leave `a` and `b` unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements.*

Comment: @VisioN Notice note on MDN:  "If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this"

Comment: @VisionN: to fix spec problem:  function sort1 (a, b) {
    if (a === b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return Math.abs(a % 2) - Math.abs(b % 2) || a - b;
};

Comment: @VisionN: To fix the spec problem better: console.log(n.sort(function (a, b) {return (a & 1) - (b & 1) || a - b || 1;}));​

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as follows:

```
n.sort(function(a,b){
 if (a % 2 != b % 2 ){
   return a%2;
  }else {
      return (a - b) > 0 ? 1 : -1; 
  }
});
```

Working sample is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7vv7C/).

Edit:

```
n.sort(function(a,b){
 if (a % 2 != b % 2 ){
     return a%2 == 0 ? -1 : 1; // this is the fix :)
  }else {
      return (a - b) > 0 ? 1 : -1; 
  }
});
```

Edit 2:
I've modifed the code for negative numbers. See [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7vv7C/).

```
n.sort(function(a,b){
 if (a % 2 != b % 2 ){
   return Math.abs(a)%2;
  }else {
      return a > b ? 1 : -1; 
  }
});
```

Comment: Not as per accepted result. The result is a mixture of odd and even :(

Answer (score 0):

My try:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jMZV/2/)

```
var n = [10,20,21,4,5,6,7,99,0,-12,12,13,-45,10,20,21,-13,4,5,6,7,99,0,12,13,10,-99,20,21,4,5,6,7,99,0,12,13,10,20,21,4,5,6,7,99,-15,-18,0,12,13];

function sort(a, b) {
    if (!(a % 2) && !(b % 2)) {
        return a > b ? 1 : -1;
    }
    if ((a % 2) && (b % 2)) {
        return a > b ? 1 : -1;
    }
    if ((a % 2) && !(b % 2)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
console.log(n.sort(sort));​
```