# JavaScript. Array .sort() method returns different results for Chrome and Firefox if array contains duplicate numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting, firefox

I have array containing random numbers. When I trying to sort this array via `.sort()` method, the result is different if array contains duplicate numbers. The code below works differently in Chrome and Firefox:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,15,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,0,2,3].sort(function(a, b) {
  console.log("a=", a, "b=", b)
})
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ocm1ZSXgkoCM7FQeH0v5

Does it bug ? How to fix this behavior to have same result in Chrome and FF ?

Comment: Your `sort` function is _wrong_. Since it returns `undefined` for every single comparison, it's _expected_ that sorting won't work.

Comment: @vlaz I've updated the plunk

Comment: @vlaz please look my latest comments under answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40516655/5397119

Comment: I have. You cannot do what you're trying to do with this function. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison/24080786#24080786) for why that might be a problem.

Comment: @vlaz pls check if my answer is doing what he is trying to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works with a proper return value.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,15,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,0,2,3];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
console.log(array);

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a & 1) - (b & 1) || a - b;
});
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this code still returns different results in console.log() for Chrome and FF

Comment: I really doubt it

Comment: the sort order is not necessarily stable for the same values.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo what do you mean by "result"? Do you mean the array at the end or the console output in compare function?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo the result is the same. Ignore the other output - the browsers simply use different sorting algorithms.

Comment: @JohnnyAW ok, I want to sort the array of numbers so that the first will be odd numbers, then odd numbers. But I don't need to sort this numbers in asc/desc. Only replace. For example, the code example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13139947/5397119 works differently for Chrome and FF if array contains duplicate numbers

Comment: but I can't do this because Chrome and FF compare pair of elements differently

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo so what do you expect to happen? Two different sorting algorithms are deployed. Your output will be sorted as much as you've allowed it to be sorted. If you don't consider `1` and `3` to be different then they might or might not get shifted along. If you want the sorting to be stable, use a stable sorting function. Right now you are not allowing JS to sort it correctly because different inputs produce a different output.

Comment: ok, pls show us different results, made by chrome and ff for the compare function in the answer you posted, im really excited about seeing different sort result with the same compare function!

Comment: @JohnnyAW it's simple - use `return true` and you will get different results. Heck, Chrome might even give you different sorting for different _sizes_ of datasets. If the array is big enough, over 10 elements, I believe, Chrome uses a different sorting algorithm, so a non-stable sorting function will produce a different (but consistent) result than with 9 and below.

Comment: @vlaz ohh wait, I think I got his problem

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo your plunker only gives me: Hello Plunker!

Comment: @JohnnyAW see console.log output

Comment: @JohnnyAW again, Bergi has a brilliant writeup on sorting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison/24080786#24080786). Also, yeah, Plunkr is bad - you have to open the console to see the output. It's annoying. It's as if JSBin and StackOverflow (with snippets) are the only websites that realised how to do it properly

Comment: @vlaz I ment that he could show us one of the browser giving us wrong sorting.

Comment: @vlaz thx for the link, I'm aware about different sorting algorthms and stuff, we actually discussed some of them(qui-sort, merge-sort) in the lessons back then. It just took time for me to get his problem:)

Answer (score 4):

Since [sort()  is not necessarily stable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), you need to save the position of an element before sorting and use it as compare parameter if the value is equal, if you want to keep the position in the result array . But the problem in your case is, you have multiple values and can't just look up the position in the starting-array. You need to wrap your values in objects:

```js
var values= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,15,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,0,2,3];
var wrappedValues = [];
//first create wrapped values
for(var i = 0;i < values.length;i++){
    wrappedValues.push({value : values[i], index : i});
}
//now sort wrapped values
wrappedValues.sort(function(a, b) {
    var result = a.value % 2 - b.value % 2;
    if(result == 0){
        return a.index - b.index;
    }
    return result;
});
//now unwrappe the values:
var unwrappedValues = [];
wrappedValues.forEach(function(entry) {
    unwrappedValues.push(entry.value);
});
console.log(unwrappedValues );
```

btw. part of your Problem is in the compare function from the answer you provided:

```
return a % 2 - b % 2 || a - b;
```

this function is sorting ascending in `|| a - b` - part

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that's the decorate-sort-undecorate pattern, though it's usually done as `.map(/* decorate */).sort().map(/* undecorate */)` which avoids declaring the intermediate temporary values.

Comment: @vlaz but `.map()` creates a new Array, so how would this avoid declaring the intermediate temporary values? o.O

Comment: Well, _you_ don't have to declare them. Obviously they still exist but you don't need to care about that in your code. All you need here is input -> output and something called `wrappedValues` is merely noise. Similarly, the _name_ `unwrappedValues` is also just noise - do you really, honestly care that the values were once wrapped in _something_ when they are presented as plain values again?

Comment: @vlaz oh wait, you said "declared".. nvm. I misread again :D Yeah, you're right, that would be much shorter. But I will still leave the code this way so the OP can easier understand it.